# Downloading a PDF from the internet results in partial file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, download

I am trying to download a pdf from Amazon S3 using the code below. However, the file only partially downloads and can't be opened. (The code is amalgam of other SO answers and random Google searching).

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
long byteCount;
string filename = "random.pdf";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(<url-to-s3>);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

while ((byteCount = resStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    if (Response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the file is bigger than 32k, in which case you're flushing and closing the response before all bytes are read. Additionally, you should be sending the client only the bytes read (denoted by `byteCount`) and not the entire buffer regardless. You also don't need to set the `Response.ContentType` and add duplicate headers for each buffering operation. Try:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);

while ((byteCount = resStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);    
}

Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

I'm also assuming you're not getting an error *per se* - likely because `Response.End()` would disconnect the client so `Response.IsClientConnected` returns false.

---

That being said, you should be able to just use [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to copy the streams without explicitly controlling the read-buffer-write operation yourself:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);

reStream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);

Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

If you want to specify 32k buffers, just use the [`Stream.CopyTo(Stream, int)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783870%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
reStream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream, 32768);
```

Comment: I am not using .NET 4.5, so I can't use CopyTo().

Comment: Also, using the code without CopyTo(), the browser churns without finishing (no file download, no navigation to another page).

Comment: Can you debug where it is getting stuck?